# Memcache for pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory-management, pagination, memcached

This feels like a really bad idea on implementation and I'm not sure of the speed savings given the potential cost in memory.

Using Dalli and Memecache to store a set of data that gets pulled on every page request that needs to be paginated. Its a lot of data so I'd really rather not keep hitting the database if possible, but I also don't know how expensive this operation is for memory, both in memcache as well as just in system memory. To paginate, I do basically the following:

1. Call to memcache to see if given data exists
2. If found, get data and go to 4.
3. If not found, get from database and cache
4. **Dup object** because object is frozen. ?? <-- seems like a really bad idea...
5. Return paginated data for display.

[WillPaginate](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) has to perform actions on the dataset coming out of the DB but it throws a "can't modify frozen object" error.

How much bad is this? `dup`-ing a large object (which is cached to save time in calls to the db) seems like it will end up chewing up a lot of extra memory and run the GC a lot more than needs be. Anyone suggest some ways around this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with the objects at a Model / List view, you can also cache the rendered html.  You can even pre-cache the contents for an extra boost :)